# Datanucleus mongodb embedded object

Tags: mongodb, orm, datanucleus

Does Datanucleus support mongodb embedded object?

I have collection "group" where one field represents embedded object:

```
@PersistenceCapable(table = "group")
public class MyGroup
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY, column = "_id")
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @Embedded
    private Person person;

    // getters/setters
    ...
}

@EmbeddedOnly
@PersistenceCapable
public class Person
{
    private String _id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // getters/setters
    ...
}
```

Retrieve record by ID (and marshal to JSON with Jackson)

```
MyGroup myGroup = persistenceManager.getObjectById(MyGroup.class, id)
```

Configuration:

```
@Bean
public PersistenceManager persistenceManager() throws IOException
{
    Properties jdoProperties = getProperties();

    PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(jdoProperties);
    return pmf.getPersistenceManager();
}
```

The result I get is:

```
{
  "id": "523119baac8c950b674d9245",
  "name": "GXVTXCCXB",
  "person": {
    "_id": null,
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null
  }
}
```

The embedded object is not populated by it's values.

Comment: based on what persistence code? based on what retrieval code? what does the log say?

Comment: @NeilStockton Please see updated info.

Comment: and the persistence code, and the log?

Comment: I have no persistence code. I'm just trying to fetch object.

Comment: so what you're saying is you already have objects in the database, persisted by some other mechanism? so maybe you haven't mapped the embedded columns correctly in your JDO mappings information

Comment: You can see an code example. The structure and objects mapping are very simple. I got embedded object in result but it's empty...

Comment: and you can see that they don't match what the default is for your JDO provider

Answer (score 0):

If you have existing data not generated by your JDO provider then you must make sure that your mapping matches what is in the database. In this case you seem to want "columns" of embedded fields as "firstName" and "lastName" but your class is not configured to embed them with those names. Update your annotation to be

```
@Embedded(members={
            @Persistent(name="firstName", columns=@Column(name="firstName")),
            @Persistent(name="lastName", columns=@Column(name="lastName"))})
private Person person;
```

See [JDO docs for embedded fields](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jdo/orm/embedded.html).